# R:Plotly - Creating Multiple boxplots in one graph as a group

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data set like below for 250 Ids

```
ID A_Male A_Female B_Male B_Female C_Male C_Female
1    25     75      40     60        20    80
2    30     70      50     50        80    20
3    50     50      30     70        20    80
```

I want to create a boxplot using plotly in R grouping by A,B,C. My boxplot should look like below (Sample plot).

[image: Required Boxplot]

But I do not have a variable column to group this.

Is there a way I can create this in R using plot_ly package?? 
Thanks.

Comment: look at `data.table::melt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with some processing of your data using the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages before you plot.  Assume that your data frame is `df`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

plot_data <- df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID) %>%
  separate(variable, c("group","gender"), sep = "\\_")
```

You would then use `plot_data` to create your boxplots using plot.ly with your new group and gender variables.

```
plot_ly(plot_data, x = ~group, y = ~value, color = ~gender, type = "box")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this simply (where df is the sample data you provided, to start with):

```
df <- melt(df, id='ID')
df[c('type', 'gender')] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$variable), split='_'))

plot_ly(df, x = type, y = value, color = gender, type = "box") %>% 
         layout(boxmode = "group", 
         xaxis = list(title=''), 
         yaxis = list(title='Percentage (%)'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both the methods above works for this scenario